# Is it possible to write function for pageSizeOptions on change for angular material paginator?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Hi here i am applying angular material paginator like below

```
<mat-paginator
  [length]="100"
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

so here my point is it possible to apply  change method on pageSize option change like select and also for next and prev can we apply the function for that ?
some thing like

```
<mat-paginator
  [length]="100"
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
  (change)="onPageSelectionChange()"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

[image]

and also i tried the

```
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" 
(change)="onPageSelectionChange($event)" 
(page)="pageEvents($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

here page event is working but how can i call my next and prev function methods

```
    onPageSelectionChange(event:PageEvent) {
       alert('working');
       console.log(event)
    
    }

    nextButton() {
      console.log('next button pressed')
    }
    previousButton() {
      console.log('prev button press')
    }

    pageEvents(event: PageEvent) {
       console.log(event);
    }
```

stackblitz url = https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vv9tdz

Comment: Use (page) output event. See more here https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

Comment: in all **event binding** can call a function with the argument `$event`: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#target-event so use `(change)="onPageSelectionChange($event)"` and make in your function `onPageSelectionChange(event:PageEvent){console.log(event)}`

Comment: @Eliseo i tried your approach by setting change event i didnt any values but i tried (page) event got some value i am not sure the whether it is right approach or not and how can i place the next and prev button function in that ? updated a stack blitz

Comment: ::glups:: yes, it's true, is the event `(page)`. In event you has event.pageSize with the value, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-takgby?file=src/app/paginator-overview-example.ts, with the response you should has all you need. Take account that if you change the pageSize, you change the page index too

Comment: @Eliseo   one small doubt how can i tell which button is pressed i mean next button or prev button ?

Comment: @Eliseo   like this   if(event.pageIndex > this.pageNumber) {
      // Clicked on next
      console.log('next button')
    } else {
      // Clicked on previous button
      console.log('prev button')
    }

Comment: are you getting data through a API call in each pagination change?

Comment: @TechieBoy, I updated the stackblitz, I hope this help you

Comment: @Eliseo so here [length] means tota number of records right ?